# Android - Bitmap - Fatal Signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I have a project where I need a custom canvas (white sheet) like a view.

The activity will have two divisions

1. The aforementioned canvas.
2. A list/recycler view with images (ignore the temporary LinearLayout instead of list/recycler view)

So when I click on an Image. This image will get transferred to the canvas. Where user can drag, scale, rotate or do all of these together to that image. This canvas should support up to 4-5 images at the same time.

I would like to know if there is any better alternative or I am going to the right direction.

If I am going to the right direction. Please help me on this issue.

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x180 in tid 18318 (odrob_sylvester)

Here is my Activity Class (**CanvasActivity.java**)

```
public class CanvasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = CanvasActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private WodrobView canvas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_canvas);

        canvas = (WodrobView) findViewById(R.id.canvas);
    }


    public void img1click(View view) {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wodrob_1);
        Product product = new Product(image);
        Details details = new Details("Wodrob_1", "123", 123);
        product.setDetails(details);
        WodrobHandler.addObjectToWODROB(product);
        Log.d(TAG, "img1click called");
        canvas.updateCanvas();
    }
}
```

**activity_canvas.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.wodrob.wodrob_sylvester.CanvasActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/card_margin_horizontal"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:elevation="@dimen/canvas_elevation">

        <com.example.wodrob.wodrob_sylvester.widget.WodrobView
            android:id="@+id/canvas"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/card_margin_horizontal"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:onClick="img1click"
                android:src="@drawable/wodrob_1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wodrob_2" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wodrob_3" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/wodrob_4" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Custom widget canvas (**WodrobView.java**)

```
public class WodrobView extends View {

    private static final String TAG = WodrobView.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;

    public WodrobView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public WodrobView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public WodrobView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drawingImages(canvas);
            }
        });
    }

    private void drawingImages(Canvas canvas){
        Map<Point, Product> drawMap = WodrobHandler.getObjects();
        for (Point point : drawMap.keySet()){
            Product product = drawMap.get(point);
            if (product.isAdded()) {
                Log.w(TAG, product.getDetails().getName() + " is already added!");
                continue;
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = product.getBitmap();
            Bitmap bitmapTemp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, false);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTemp, point.x, point.y, new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG));
        }

    }

    public void updateCanvas() {
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

A **WodrobHandler.java**

```
public class WodrobHandler implements WodrobHelper {

    interface WodrobHelper {
        Point[] POINTS = new Point[]{
                new Point(10, 10),
                new Point(10, 10),
                new Point(10, 10),
                new Point(10, 10)
        };
    }

    private static final String TAG = WodrobHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    private static Map<Point, Product> objects = new HashMap<>();

    private static short position = 0;

    public static boolean addObjectToWODROB(Product product){
        if (position >= 4 || position < 0){
            Set<Point> pointSet = objects.keySet();
            for (Point point:POINTS) {
                short flag = 0;
                for (Point point1:pointSet) {
                    if (point.equals(point1.x, point1.y))
                        flag++;
                }
                if (flag == 0) {
                    objects.put(point, product);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid position or full");
            return false;
        } else {
            objects.put(POINTS[position++], product);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static boolean removeObjectFromWODROB(Product product){
        if (!objects.containsValue(product)){
            Log.e(TAG, "No such product to remove");
            return false;
        }
        objects.remove(product.getPoint());
        return true;
    }

    public static Map<Point, Product> getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }

    public static void setObjects(Map<Point, Product> objects) {
        WodrobHandler.objects = objects;
    }
}
```

**Product.java**

```
public class Product {
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private Details details;

    Point point = null;

    private boolean added = false;

    public boolean isAdded() {
        return added;
    }

    public void setAdded(boolean added) {
        this.added = added;
    }

    public Product(Bitmap bitmap) {
        //Getting bitmap from drawable resource
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public Details getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public Point getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(Point point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public void setDetails(Details details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
}
```

**Details.java**

```
public class Details {
    private String name, id;
    private int cost;

    public Details(String name, String id, int cost) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `objects` in `WodrobHandler` is empty. Where are code you add element?

You have to convert bitmap to mutable and avoid create bitmap in onDraw. Create it on Construtor. Code create bitmap mutable:

```
Bitmap. createScaledBitmap(souce,souce.getWidth(),source.getHeight,false);
```

Comment: Well, I have got a new error now. In WodrobView.drawingImages(Canvas), getting error "only mutable bitmaps may be reconfigured" on setWidth();

Comment: You have to convert bitmap to mutable and avoid create bitmap in onDraw. Create it on Construtor. Code create bitmap mutable: `Bitmap. createBitmap(souce,souce.getWidth(),source.getHeight,false);`

Comment: A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x180 in tid 16467 (odrob_sylvester)
got this now

Comment: Check your logcat again. It seem have another error message.